# Entity Framework - Default Child Objects

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Is there a way to set default child entities for a new entity without having to query all of them using ObjectQueries?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Could you rephrase that? Maybe explain what you mean by the term "default child entity", or even "child entity"?

Comment: I worked with EF for about six months - I guess I missed the term "Default Child Object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. You can set the EntityKey directly. This means you will not be able to access the value of the child entity, but sometimes you don't need to do that. There is information about doing this in [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/25/tip-7-faking-foreign-key-properties-in-net-3-5-sp1.aspx).

Comment: Nice!  Exactly what I was looking for.  I guess you're a lot smarter than the downvoters, Craig.  I thought my question was worded in a fairly straightforward manner...